# ASP.NET assigning an integer value pulled from database to a variable and using it for if/else check

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having this bit of problem I'm hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction as I don't have much hair left to pull out anymore.

I'm writing this ASP.NET program which has a Login Page and I need to fetch an integer value from the database after username/password authentication (which I was able to manage) and run it through an if/else block to determine the page to which I will be redirecting the user. My problem begins there.

By walking through the code I found out that after the fetching, it seems like the assignment was successfully done but the assigned value is the password i acquired earlier. So when it comes to the if/else block, none of the options match and it falls to the else option failing to redirect to the necessary page. I am using the same query variable I used when fetching the password from the database, just ediiting its value before executing the command. Here is the code:

```
query = String.Format("SELECT u_accesslevel FROM users WHERE u_email='{0}';", username);
int accesslevel = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

This is where I execute the query and assign the variable. And:

```
if (accesslevel == 1)
{
     Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx");
}
else if (accesslevel == 2)
{
     Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
}
else if (accesslevel == 3)
{
     Response.Redirect("Page3.aspx");
}
else
     Response.Write("ERROR!");
```

I'm using OleDbConnection to connect to the database and I'm using an Access database file to hold the data.

For additional details about the project and myself, there is no concern for security. It is for a school project which won't be opened again after its grading. I just need to get the program running. While I have some programming experience with C# (no database interaction though), ASP.NET and web technologies in general are new ground for me and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing. Is there a better way to do this instead of using .ExecuteScalar()?

PS: I'm also fetching the user id from the same table and using the same assignment operation to create a session object for the user before they are redirected to their requested page. I can't be sure if that one works correctly either because of the problem above. The piece of code for that is:

```
int userid = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
Session["_id"] = userid.ToString();
```

I'd be grateful if you could check if that's correct as well, since its practically the same thing (or looks like it). Thanks!

Comment: After the assignment, what is the value of  accesslevel and why aren't you using a switch/case statement?

Comment: I used a switch when tying for the first time, it wasn't working so i decided to change it to if/else out of frustration. No logic there I know. Value of accesslevel is somehow the password i fetched in the previous query execution. I'm using the same query variable and just changing its string value before the next execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace your if code with next

```
if (accesslevel >= 1 && accesslevel <= 3)
{
     Response.Redirect(string.Format("Page{0}.aspx", accesslevel));
}
else {
     Response.Write("ERROR! " + accesslevel);
}
```

so it will print you error with code and then you will see more info, also have optimized your if a bit since it was copy paste. when you run code add you response with error to see which access level user has

PS: but i think issue is that you query is not returning right result, try to see which query it builds, maybe it pass incorrect username or some thing else happends, in addition please note that if you are using Session that after build it is cleared, so if you read username from session it could be empty

PS: now i got whats wrong

```
query = String.Format("SELECT u_accesslevel FROM users WHERE u_email='{0}';", username);
int accesslevel = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

here you set new query but doesnot assign it to command so replace it with following

```
query = String.Format("SELECT u_accesslevel FROM users WHERE u_email='{0}';", username);
command.CommandText = query;
int accesslevel = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: thanks for the optimization i'll definitely use that. About the accesslevel, I already know what value it gets and it's getting the password from the previous query. I don't know why that happens. I'll edit the question to include that extra detail.

Comment: @phyrax then its simple :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought the command would use the most current query variable and wouldn't need an update. It works perfectly now.